# Why is first entry skipping a line in Visual Basic command to compile text files into Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

The intention of my code below is to compile many text files into one Excel spreadsheet.  I am able to retrieve data but the first command, to obtain the "gender" starts on the ***second*** line of the Excel spreadsheet; while the subsequent commands (e.g. get the "first name") correctly begin populating on the ***first*** line. Any ideas how to start "gender" on line 1 as well?

```
Sub read_text()

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    workingflnm = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    i = 1 'First row
    Set fd = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    pthnm = "C:\TestFolder"
    Set fs = fd.GetFolder(pthnm)
    For Each fl In fs.Files
        If InStr(1, fl.Name, "txt", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            Set Txtobj = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
            Set Txtfl = Txtobj.getfile(fl)
            Set Txtstrm = Txtfl.openastextstream(1, -2)
            Do While Txtstrm.atendofstream <> True
                rdln = Txtstrm.readline

                If InStr(1, rdln, "ender: ", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                    'This if/then looks for the "gender" value in each text file
                    x1 = InStr(1, rdln, "ender: ", vbTextCompare)
                    strg = Left(rdln, 40)
                    Workbooks(workingflnm).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = strg
                    'i = i + 1
                End If

                If InStr(1, rdln, "irst Name: ", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                    'This if/then looks for the "first name" value in each text file
                    x1 = InStr(1, rdln, "irst Name: ", vbTextCompare)
                    strg = Left(rdln, 40)
                    Workbooks(workingflnm).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2) = strg
                    'i = i + 1
                End If

               If InStr(1, rdln, "ast Name: ", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                    'This if/then looks for the "last name" value in each text file
                    x1 = InStr(1, rdln, "ast Name: ", vbTextCompare)
                    strg = Mid(rdln, x1 + Len("ast Name: "), x2 + 50 - (x1 + Len("ast Name: ")))
                    Workbooks(workingflnm).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) = strg
                    i = i + 1
                End If

            Loop

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The content of each text file looks like this:

```
Contact Information 

Name: Smith, John   Home Phone: 6465551234
Street Address: 1313 Mockingbird    Work Phone: 
Apt or Unit:    Fax: 
City/State/Zip: YONKERS,NY,10701    Email: john@john.john
County: Westchester
Contact Time:   Respond Time: 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

User Info 

First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Date of Birth: 11/7/1957
Gender: Male
```

Comment: are you sure that the first line in your txt file does actually have the word `ender:`? it may be that the first IF is never executed

Comment: For same reason the code wouldn't work if "Gender" so I had to put just "ender".  (And the same for the other look up entries.)

Comment: Looks like you might be overwriting it since `i` is not being incremented in the gender `if` statement.  Step through your code to see if it's populating and then being re-written.

Comment: +1 for editing and providing more details

Answer (score 3):

I think your method is fundamentally flawed. Because you are incrementing `i` at the wrong time. Because `i` is shared between each piece of data, every time you increment `i` you'll be on the next row.

My suggestion: Use `ReadAll` instead. Your data should have a delimiter in it so that you can parse each record and be certain you have the same row for the same record. If there is no delimiter, how do you know to go to a new record anyway?

This would make your code something like this:

```
dim currentRow as integer, i as integer, j as integer
dim data as string
currentRow = 1
'for each file you'll need to set up this loop
data = Txtstrm.ReadAll
records = Split(records, "YOURDELIMETER HERE")
For i = LBound(records) To UBound(records)
    lines = Split(records, vbNewLine)
    For j = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
                    rdln = lines(j)

                If InStr(1, rdln, "ender: ", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                    'This if/then looks for the "gender" value in each text file
                    x1 = InStr(1, rdln, "ender: ", vbTextCompare)
                    strg = Left(rdln, 40)
                    Workbooks(workingflnm).Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1) = strg
                    'Do not increment i manually as that is handled by for loop
                End If
               ' etc...
    Next

Next
currentRow = currentRow + i
'next file
```

Comment: +1 ive looked through the code and realized that there was a logical error in it. Thanks for pointing it out, well spotted